# SSRS Set current hour to parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

i got one question. I want to have a parameter @currenthour which capture the current hour as default. As example, if the current time is 8.15am, so the parameter capture only the value of 08. Hope to have support from you guys as I am very new to SSRS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use SSRS expression, something like:

`=Hour(Now())`

The expression above will return hour of current time. So now if the current time is `15:26` it will return `15`.